# avoid circular linking in ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. I have model as below :-

```
class Role {
  String id;
  String role_name;
  Role parentid;  // Parent of role
}
```

I want to avoid circular linking as `NewRole1` is parent and child of itself, and only role where `parentid == null` those will enable and remain will be in disable.

I have written the code below, but it is not working correctly.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="role_name" id="field_role_name" 
       ng-model="role.role_name" ng-model="testname" 
       required ng-maxlength="45">

<select class="form-control" id="field_role_r_name" name="role_r_name" 
       ng-model="role.parentid"
       ng-options="role1 as role1.role_name disable when (role1.role_name==role.role_name || role1.parentid.id!=null) for role1 in roles track by role1.id">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Its stops `NewRole1` to be parent of itself, but my `role1.parentid.id!=null` when condition is not working correctly. I want to disable all role who has parentid.
Can someone guide me is there anything wrong in above.

Comment: why you do this complex logic in the template? can you filter the roles in the controller and simply display it in the template?

Comment: ok i will try to do that, and will update you ,  but i wanted to show the details in drop down with disable.